# convert JSON to string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms

I have a string that contains JSON data and I want to convert it to string or string array in C#.

I'm getting exception of type `JSONReaderException`

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: :. Path '', line 1, position 7

What is the meaning of it?

Here is my code:

```
string requestType = Request.QueryString[0].ToString();
JObject json = JObject.Parse(requestType);
JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(requestType.Substring(1,requestType.Length-2));
```

The data is sent to the server from AJAX request. I'm attaching the request:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "AJAXRequests.aspx",
                        type: "get",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "first": "getevent","second":"data" }),
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function (response){
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            alert("Problem in sending data to the server.\n Please check your internet connection and try again");
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: can you post your json data ?

Comment: @liorko post Json Please

Comment: Json is a *string* with a specific format. What is your input string and what do you expect as output? The code you posted doesn't help

Comment: As stated in the exception, the string probably contains some non-JSON data, so you may need to sanitize the string before trying to parse it. As others already suggested, please provide a sample of the string before expecting a more specific answer.

Comment: BTW I'm pretty certain you *can't* pass a json string as a URL query parameter without URL encoding it. Which means you'll have to decode it before trying to parse it

Comment: not sure why you are instantiating `JavaScriptSerializer` in your code, since you are using JSON.Net to deserialize.

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj i posted the JSON

Comment: What is your need..cleary explain ...i con't see any JSON string in your post..please post input string and "also desired output"

Comment: I debugged the received string in the server side and got this string:
"{\r\n  \"first\": \"getevent\",\r\n  \"second\": \"data\"\r\n}".
The desired output is an array of string that contains the words that in the string:
String[] s = {"first","getevent","second","data"}

Answer (score 1):

A `JSONReaderException` with the message "Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: :. Path '', line 1, position 7"

means,

the string you are parsing has some JSON at the start followed by something else that is not JSON.

---

In this case, the part that is not JSON starts a position 7 on line 1.

Comment: Also note the OP is using a query string parameter as input. Either there is no valid json to begin with, or the OP has to decode it before parsing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, agreed, the OP should probably be doing a `POST` and reading JSON from the body, if the `Content-Type` is appropriate. However, I'm answering the question that was asked.